# Displaying UTF-8 in ERB says "incompatible character encodings" (no database involved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, erb

In my ERB page, I want to display one of the country names configured in this CSV file:

```
Suisse
Deutschland
日本
```

Here is the code that loads the CSV in `config/initializers`:

```
require 'csv'
COUNTRIES = CSV.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/countries.csv").flatten
```

Here is the code in the ERB:

```
<%= "Country:" + COUNTRIES[id].to_s %>
```

I displays fine when id=0 or id=1, but when id=2 an error appears:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

...with the error pointing to the ERB line above.
How to fix it?

*No database involved, Ruby 1.9.2-p180. UTF-8 from localization files is displayed fine.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [CSV#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/CSV.html#M001343) docs:

> This method also understands an additional :encoding parameter that you can use to specify the Encoding of the data in the file to be read. You must provide this unless your data is in Encoding::default_external(). CSV will use this to deterime how to parse the data.

So just to be safe, I would first use

```
COUNTRIES = CSV.read("/Users/dumitru/test.csv", { encoding: "UTF-8" }).flatten
```

and check what

```
COUNTRIES[2].encoding.name
```

says a) directly after `CSV#read` and b) when executed in your ERB template. If it says "US-ASCII" there then you should check whether something accidentally changes your COUNTRIES after parsing them. At least you can then be sure that something's odd inbetween.

I would also prefer

```
<%= "Country:" + COUNTRIES[id] %>
```

since you already have strings there. But I don't think this will cure the issue, though.

I couldn't imagine that something actually changed the contents of the string but maybe the encoding got reassociated as US-ASCII. So you might have a good chance to use

```
COUNTRIES[2].force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

with your string in order to enforce the association back to UTF-8. If that doesn't help I'd try

```
COUNTRIES[2].encode("UTF-8")
```

If all of these methods fail, I would need to know the encoding at the time you try to render the string in your ERB template to help you further.

Comment: Thanks I added `, { encoding: "UTF-8" }` as you suggested and that works! Strangely, my Encoding::default_external() is #<Encoding:UTF-8>

Comment: That is strange indeed, according to the docs it should work automatically then... If I try it on my machine it behaves correctly and parses it as UTF-8 strings. But at least you have a solution that's working for now :)

Answer (score 0):

seems that your csv file isn't saved in UTF-8, try to convert it to utf-8

edit:
I've tested the above example on my local mac, using the same ruby version and it works without issues. I've created a csv from scratch and tested on irb.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > require 'csv'
=> true  
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > COUNTRIES = CSV.read("/Users/dumitru/test.csv").flatten
=> ["Suisse", "Deutschland", "\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > "Country:" + COUNTRIES[0].to_s
=> "Country:Suisse" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > "Country:" + COUNTRIES[2].to_s
=> "Country:\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC"
```

Comment: Confirmed with the Linux `isutf8` tool: my file is already UTF-8

Comment: About your edit: Thanks! I tried the same commands on my Ubuntu 2011.04 and I get the exact same output. But still, the ERB template fails on the Japanese one.